# Menu dropdown hover conflict with slider link below

Tags: jquery, html, css, conflict

We appear to be having a conflict on our site homepage, where a link that sits below our dropdown menu is causing it to close the menu prematurely if the cursor enters the area the link occupies.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

The homepage is http://www.weddingideasmag.com and the link I'm trying to test is called 2014 Awards, under the main Awards tab.

This is definitely a slider link issue as the problem is only happening on the homepage where the slider links are. I have attached a screenshot of the problem area below.

[image]

Here is the same area highlighted in Chrome Developer Tools. I thought it may be a z-index issue but even if I change the dropdown ul z-index to greater than the link area the problem still persists.

[image]

The css for the dropdown menu is…

```
position: absolute;
top: auto;
display: none;
float: left;
zoom: 1;
z-index: 10;
margin: 0 0 40px -1px;
padding: 20px 0 6px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 0 #999;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 0 #999;
box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 0 #999;
border: 1px solid #CCC;
background: #fafafa;
color: #676767;
```

And the css for the slider li element is…

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 5%;
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what meaningful code to add, as I'm not sure what the problem is - If I did have a clue I would include some. As to the problem description, how is that not included in my post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `a.flex-next`'s  `z-index` to 9 instead of a random number as 99 which is > than the `z-index` of the dropdown ( `z-index: 10` ). Seems to work, but your styles are generally quite messy.

Comment: Thank you @fzzle very much appreciated. In what way are they messy? Most of them are the default Woothemes stylesheets :-(

Comment: You're welcome. Stylesheets always seem messy through the DevTools. You should've posted the relevant styles from the start. Probably also why you had so many downvotes.

Answer (score -1):

Try pointer-events:none on your link with your menu is open

Comment: This would be a hacky fix. His problem is that the `a.flex-next` element is in front of the dropdowns.

Comment: Hi @Jeff - thansk for the suggestion. I tried that and it made the dropdown box disappear on mouse rollover - not the desired effect ;-)

Comment: It could be done  ..with a little of js, toogle a class on your flex-next link when your dropdown is visible

Comment: With a little bet a js -- you can certainly toggle a class on your flex-next when the dropdown is visible .